# A method to printout positive numbers

Tags: java, methods

I am a beginner at Java and currently studying foundation. I was given a practice test a week ago about `ProcessSet` and `theSet` which i am unable to answer and until now i am unable to figure out the correct method.
The method is suppose to printout how many positive numbers are in the set. Assuming that the set has at least one value in it. Below are codes to fill in the blanks.

```
public void processSet( _____  _____ theSet)
{
  int positives =  _____ ;
  for( _____ val  _____  _____ )
  {
    if( _____ )
    {
       _____ ;
    }
  }
   _____ ;
}
```

codes

`theSet`
`integers`
`<integers>`
`integer`
`Set<int>`
`System.out.printIn(positives)`
`1`
`0`
`return val`
`positives + val`
`=`
`system.out.print(val)`
`;`
`positives = positives + theSet`
`return positives`
`val`
`val > 0`
`positives++`
`positives`
`:`
`val < 0`
`val < = 0`
`val > 1`
`String`
`positives = positives + val`
`Set`
`<int>`

Comment: So you want us to do your home work? Attempt it first, i am sure you have some documents to reference from.

Comment: Half of those will not even go through compilation phase, so remove them and task becomes a lot easier.

Comment: i dont quite understand what you meant, which do i remove?

Comment: Try writing some of them into Java IDE like Eclipse, for example `system.out.println(val)` will not compile, because `system` cannot be resolved, `<integers>` I don't even know what that's supposed to be, `Set<int>` will not compile, because `int` is a primitive and `Set` cannot hold those.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void processSet(Set set)
{
    int numberOfPositiveNumbers = 0;

    for (int number: set) {
        if(number >0){
          numberOfPositiveNumbers++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(numberOfPositiveNumbers);
}
```

Comment: how does this print out *how many positive numbers are in the set* ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do either as [@AACoderGirl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7861837/aacodergirl) proposed

```
public void processSet(Set<Integer> setOfIntegers) {
    int numberOfPositiveNumbers = 0; // start counter with zero
    for (Integer number: setOfIntegers) {
        if(number >0){ // check only values that are greater than zero
          numberOfPositiveNumbers++; // add one to counter
        }
    }
    System.out.print(numberOfPositiveNumbers); // print results
}
```

or with streams:

```
   public void processSet( Set<Integer> theSet){
        System.out.print(theSet.stream().filter(i->i>0).count());
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, your post helped a lot. After testing things out, i managed to get the 'seemly' correct answer according to my friend whom has done the question last week.

Comment: Please then resolve the question, so that it will dessapear from open list.